# Best way to implement nodejs "service"

Tags: node.js, mongodb

So, I have this application where I hold insurance expiration dates. My client wants to be notified when an expiration date is seven days from the present day. How do I implement this "service"? 
I'm using MongoDb and Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to make your process run at certain intervals and see if there are any new items that matches your criteria.

To see how to make your code run at certain intervals, read Scheduled Jobs and Custom Clock Processes in the Heroku documentation:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes